# Why should you not just buy the chain with more links?

Tags: chain

I have the choice of buying a 114 or a 116 link chain for the same price.

Why would I not buy the longer one and shorten it?

In my case my bike previously had 108 links, and assuming that was correct, 114 should be sufficient, but given it may need shortened, is it not worth buying the longer chain just in case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your old chain was sized appropriately for your drivetrain, and you're not changing anything, then you're going to shorten the new chain to the length of the old chain (via counting links, or lying the chains on the ground and pinching them together).

Then, you throw the remaining links into your tool box in case of needing them as spares for a repair in the future. Eventually, you have enough spare links in your tool box and you start throwing the spare links away when you get a new chain (or better yet, as Kibbee suggests, donate them to a bike co-op/shop).

So, it doesn't matter which one you buy in the long run -- the chain just has to be long enough to begin with (unless its a bike which needs a longer chain, like a tandem in which case you need to buy 2 chains and combine them).

Comment: Eventually you could use all the left over pieces of chain and put together a whole new chain. At 8 extra links per chain, that would only take 14 new chains to create a whole chain from the left over links.

Comment: Not really a good idea to build up a chain from leftover pieces -- wouldn't be nearly as strong as a new chain, since a lot of the rivets would be pretty damaged. I'd be willing to splice maybe one section of chain  into a new chain for a repair. But in principle, if you were very cheap, you could do that.

Comment: More meant as a joke, buy you should probably donate them to your local bike co-op rather than start throwing them out when you get too many extras.

Comment: What if you needed (say) 100 links, buy two 120-link chains, take 50 from each one, your spare link sections are 70 links long and you can easily build all your chains from two sections.

Comment: Sure, but you're still only getting 2 chains out of it. Sorta the hot dog and hot dog bun problem; Hot dogs come in packs of 8, buns come in packs of 10, so if you want no left overs, you need 5 packs of hot dogs and 4 packs of buns. You could buy them and freeze them and thaw as necessary and eat all 40 hot dogs, or just buy an 8 pack of hot dogs, 10 buns if its just you, and eat them for a few days. On top of that, manufacturers tell you not to put other makes of chain into their chains (presumably for loyalty/money reasons, but still...)

Comment: In order to get a whole extra 100 link chain from 120 link chains, you need to buy 5 chains (so you have 600 links), which would require connecting 5 pieces of chain together at a minimum (I'm ignoring the mating of the links). If you were using bigger pieces as you suggest, you'd be buying more than 5 chains for an extra chain.Still, you're breaking the chain and weakening it more than necessary and you're also spending a decent amount of more time than necessary for a few bucks!

Comment: @Random832 Really so I buy two chains. And I cut them at 50 and combine. Now I have one (semi) good chain and two extra 70 link sections. I went from two good (one link) chains to one semi good (two link) chain and two spare links or 70 each. How am I better off?

Comment: @Batman 50+50 (spare 70 70), 70+30 (spare 40), 60+40 (spare 60), 40+60 (spare 80), then you can make two 60+40s. Since each one is made of only two segments of substantial length, it's going to be significantly better off than one made of many short segments.

Comment: Also, I assume there's an advantage to having most/all of your spare being from a single original chain, in case you need to replace or add a large section.

Comment: @Random832 - Ah, right. Its not a bad idea, but I think most people would rather do something more useful with their time (e.g. go to the pub).

Answer (score 4):

With 8 extra links you can make your own chain whip with a nice piece of wood next time you need to swap your cassette. I actually did this recently. Worker reasonably well.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that both these are from different manufacturers, or maybe slightly different product lines (DuraAce vs. Ultegra).  I can't think of why a manufacturer would bother shipping 2 identical chains with one only having 2 links more than the other. Choose one based on some other criteria such as which brand you trust more, or which is actually supposed to be better.

Comment: In this situation, they are both listed as Tiagra 4601 10 speed chains. If they are variants in any other respect, that is not advertised. (cn-4601)

Comment: A common Shimano 8-speed chain is often available from the same seller in 114,116,118 and even 120 link lengths, for very similar prices.

Comment: I looked and guess you are right, they [do exist](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ca/en/shimano-hg71-6-8-speed-chain/rp-prod128727).  I can't think of why they would do this. You'd never be able to make it so that people wouldn't have to remove links. Even on bikes with the same size cogs and cassette, the difference in chain stay length would still mean you need to adjust the chain length.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the 116 link chain just so that you have a *little* extra spare in case something goes wrong.